# react-bootstrap-table2 pagination is not working with useState

Tags: pagination, use-state, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table2 pagination in my react application.I am using a state to update the sizePerPage dynamically.But it is not working. When I console the state, I am able to see the change, but it is not updating the pagination.

```
Here is my code:
const [sizePerPage,setSizePerPage] = useState(10);
const pagination = paginationFactory({
page:1,
sizePerPage:sizePerPage,
.......
onPageChange:function(page,sizePerPage),
onSizePerPageChange:function(page,sizePerPage)
});
```

Here I am changing the state:

```
<select onChange={e=>setSizePerPage(e.target.value)}>
<option value={10}>10</option>
<option value={25}>25</option>
<option value={50}>50</option>
</select>
```

Rest of the things are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your code.

onSizePerPageChange:function(page,sizePerpage)

Should be:

onSizePerPageChange:function(page,sizePerPage)

If there is no reason you need a custom dropdown list you can use the built-in feature by doing this:

```js
 const pagination = paginationFactory({

    sizePerPageList: [{
      text: '10', value: 10
    }, {
      text: '25', value: 25
    }, {
      text: '50', value: 50
    }],
  });
```

Comment: still it is not working

Comment: If it was not the case, I am not sure, I don't know enough about the library you are using.

Comment: Could you try removing the following lines (they are events) and probably not needed to get the component working. 

onPageChange:function(page,sizePerPage),
onSizePerPageChange:function(page,sizePerPage)

Comment: I have modified the answer, to include one solution.